# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component. With "@material-ui/core": "3.9.3"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The issue is that in some random cases i got an error - "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component." at ref (webpack:///./node_modules
/@material-ui
/core/Slide/Slide.js?:261:52) .
It looks like findDomNode is deprecated in react 16, any updates to 
@next or latest versions are not helpful.

How can i resolve it ?

Updating to @next or other new versions

Comment: Please show the code where you are using the `Slide` transition.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, i do not use it directly <Slide ... i think some Mui components use it inside. Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-wind-8wxef) to code sandbox with view where app crashes with this error only on initial mounting, if reload page it renders without any errors.

Comment: Your sandbox is currently broken (can't find 'components/Form/Form').

Comment: @RyanCogswell yes, right you are. For implementing whole reproduceble env need to much time, may be if i will create some video it will be simplier ?

Comment: No, a video will not be helpful. Please find the simplest version of your code that still reproduces the error (i.e. remove any code that isn't necessary to reproduce the error). That is what your sandbox should contain.